# Rails syntax error in one-to-many associations exercise in Lynda Rails 3 tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**What is the problem and how can I fix it?**

When in rails console I run `page.editors`

and get the following syntax errors:

```
...simple_cms/app/models/admin_user.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
  scope: named, lambda {|first,last| ...
        ^
...simple_cms/app/models/admin_user.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
```

**Here is my code...**

**admin_user.rb**

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :username, :first_name, :last_name
  # To configure a different table name
  # set_table_name("admin_users")

  has_and_belongs_to_many :pages

  scope: named, lambda {|first,last| where(:first_name => first, :last_name => last)}

end
```

**page.rb**

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :name, :permalink, :position

  belongs_to :subject
  has_many :sections
  has_and_belongs_to_many :editors, :class_name => "AdminUser"
end
```

**alter_users.rb**

```
class AlterUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    rename_table("users", "admin_users")
    add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, :limit => 25)
    change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :limit => 100)
    rename_column("admin_users", "password", "hashed_password")
      add_column("admin_users", "salt", :string, :limit => 40)
      puts "*** About to add an index ***"
      add_index("admin_users", "username")
  end

  def down
    remove_index("admin_users", "username")
    remove_column("admin_users", "salt")
    rename_column("admin_users", "hashed_password", "password")
    change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :default => "", :null => false)
    remove_column("admin_users", "username")
    rename_table("admin_users", "users")
  end
end
```

**create_admin_users_pages_join.rb**

```
class CreateAdminUsersPagesJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :admin_users_pages, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer "admin_user_id"
        t.integer "page_id"
    end
    add_index :admin_users_pages, ["admin_user_id", "page_id"]
  end

  def down
    drop_table :admin_users_pages
  end
end
```

Don't read below this line:
Stack Overflow wanted me to add more text because this question has a lot of code.  But I thought having the code would help those who want to help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the colon on scope, and put it before named:

```
scope: named, lambda {|first,last| ...
scope :named, lambda {|first,last| ...
```